# Watcher automation in Mocha

Tags: node.js, tdd, npm, mocha.js

I would like to achieve automation of motcha --watcher feature using package.json file without globally installing mocha.

One of npm features is to allow add custom scripts into npm command. Previously I configured test runner successfully and I can type in bash now:

```
npm test
```

Everything works fine, so I would like also do something similar because

```bash
./node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha --watch app.js test.js"
```

is not too efective.

My goal is to run mocha watcher by typing in bash:

```bash
npm watch
```

Unfortunately watcher doesn't run - instead I see standard output of npm command without parameters. It looks like my custom script wasn't registered by npm.

Here is my actual package.json file

```json
{
  "name": "screencast",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha test.js", // works properly after typing 'npm test'
    "watch": "mocha --watch app.js test.js" // Syntax looks ok, but command 'npm watch' d
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.10.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "mocha": "^2.0.1",
    "supertest": "^0.15.0"
  }
}
```

Anyone had this issue before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a 'custom' script like `watch`, you have to do `npm run watch` instead of `npm watch`

Comment: Thanks, it works for me. 
It looks like, that it is npm built-in shortcut for `npm test`.
[link]https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/test[/link]

Comment: Glad to help! Please accept answer (or something. I don't actually know how this site works too well :) )